# Which UI they used for CNN application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell, transparent

I'm getting stack in the design UI for an news application, i just want to make a transparent image under the 1st cell in a UITableView, and the Bar Menu on the top also transparent, which control they used for this one, like the below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1C8N.png

Could anyone help me....

Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a UITableView, where the first cell is customized in order to contain the large image. Then, they might be using a UIScrollView as the view for the first section, or a custom header view for the whole table - depends if that top stories "scroller" scrolls together with the rest of the talbe.

The rest is a "traditional" combination of a tab bar and a navigation controller.